# Eclipse plug-in for search file with path

Tags: java, eclipse

As working on enterprise application. There are lots of java project (13 project) in my eclipse, which all build with Ant and generate Estore.ear.

While working we all use cntrl+r. I need a plugin or suggest a way to developed or improvise the cntrl+r search with Path matching too.

If anyone think on this way share your though or you know any plug which search with path. share with us

Comment: *"lots of java project (13 project) in my eclipse"* - "Oh, my sweet summer child..."

Comment: PS, I think what @GergelyBacso means is that 13 projects is not very much at all, it is not unusual for people to have dozens of projects in their workspace. One of the tools to help manage this is mylyn, have a look at the tutorial for setting it up: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mylyn/article.html

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming you mean open resources dialog, which by default is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

You can use wildcards and other special values in the search, for example (from the [docs](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-open-resource.htm?cp=0_4_4_4_1)):

> **Folder prefixes:** Both pattern kinds also support folder prefixes. If
>   the pattern contains a /, the part before the last / is used to match
>   a path in the workspace, e.g. "org.eclipse.ui/plugin.xml". Or a bit
>   more complex: "/ui.html" matches e.g. files called
>   "package.html" in a folder named "ui" (but not in folders like
>   "uitools" or "*/ui/internal").

These docs are available right on the dialog, press the help icon then 
`Open Resource dialog`:

[image: open resource dialog]